# Random variable distributed on grid

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a real random variable and $\phi$ its characteristic function. Show that there exist real $a,b$ such that $P\left(X \in a+b\mathbb{Z} \right) = 1$ if and only if there exists a nonzero $x$ such that $\left|\phi(x)\right| = 1$.

Any ideas or hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: How can the weighted average of points on a unit circle not end up in the interior of the circle?

Comment: Any attempt would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can start with this : according to the triangle inequality, $|\phi(\theta)| \leq E(|e^{i\theta X}|)=1$ with equality if and only if there exists $u \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|u|=1$ such that $e^{i\theta X} = u$ a.e.